# Closing a div moves the page up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I'm making a page where you can open and close descriptions.
The page works perfectly on firefox, but on other browser like Chrome, the page seems to go up as you open and close the other divs.

EDIT : the page goes up when I close a menu under another one. But not the other way.
**here is a link so you can see what is happening with chrome :**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlyAH.jpg

I suppose the problem is `$(this).parent('.sub-menu').siblings().find('ul').slideUp('fast');`
How can I avoid that?
Thanks a lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".exposition").on('click',function(){
   
   var hello = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $('.photos-evenements').hide();
   $('[id='+ hello + ']').show();
});
});

$( document ).ready(function(open) {


  $('.sub-menu ul').hide();
  $('.sub-menu a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('.sub-menu').siblings().find('ul').slideUp('fast'); // to hide all ul expect this one
    $(this).parent('.sub-menu').children('ul').slideToggle(200);
  });



  $('.sub-menu a').click(function(open) {
    open.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```css
.photos-evenements{
    display:none; 
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 90vh;
}

.exemple {
  height:100vh;
  background-color:lavender;
}
```

```html
<div class="exemple">hi</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class='sub-menu'> <a href='#' class="exposition"  data-id="divId1">1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li> When opened, i'm a description, I'm not supposed to move the page when opened or closed.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                        <li class='sub-menu'> <a href='#' class="exposition"  data-id="divId2">2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li> I'm supposed to close 1 and don't move the page up
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        
            </ul>
<div class="exposition">
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId1" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/Performances%20OK.jpg" data-id="divId1"/></div>
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId1" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/333_3.png" data-id="divId1"/></div>
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId1" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/333_1.png" data-id="divId1"/></div>
</div>



<div class="exposition">
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId2" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/Performances%20OK.jpg" data-id="divId2"/></div>
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId2" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/333_3.png" data-id="divId1"/></div>
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId2" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/333_1.png" data-id="divId1"/></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: missing the jquery flag?

Comment: I don't think it's the solution to your answer, but the following markup is invalid:`<img id="divId1" ...` because there is the same id on multiple img tags. The ID attribute has to be univocal.

Comment: If you hide stuff and show stuff the stuff underneath will move. It is onlz if you have visibility hidden/visible that the hidden stuff takes the same space as the visible stuff. So toggle a class instead using fadein/out

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question.
If you remove the id. The problem is still the same, that's not what i'm asking for there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you are witnessing is aggressive [scroll anchoring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor/Guide_to_scroll_anchoring) from Chrome. For some reason Chrome is anchoring the scroll on the link you clicked, while Firefox is anchoring it on some other element, possibly the container or preceding div.

It's not clear, to me at least, why there's a difference in behaviour or which is 'correct'. In any case you should be able to resolve your issue by simply disabling scroll anchoring within the menu container. To do this we can use the `overflow-anchor` property on the element where we want to disable scroll anchoring.

In the example you have given we would simply add the following code to the CSS

```
.sub-menu{
   overflow-anchor:none
}
```

This should fix the issue.

I have edited your example in the snippet below to include this (I also tidied the code up slightly to make it clearer). I have tested this in both Firefox and Chrome and the jumping of the page seems to be gone.

Obviously you will have to change what you set the `overflow-anchor:none` property on for different scripts with different class names. One approach would be to just disable scroll anchoring for the entire document by setting it on the body.

```
body{
   overflow-anchor:none
}
```

Be warned however, that scroll anchoring was introduced to counteract the very disruptive experience of what the user is currently looking at being moved unexpectedly by changes elsewhere on the document. It would be best to only disable it in select areas if possible.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".exposition").on('click',function(){
   
   var hello = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $('.photos-evenements').hide();
   $('[id='+ hello + ']').show();
});
});

$( document ).ready(function(open) {


  $('.sub-menu ul').hide();
  $('.sub-menu a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('.sub-menu').siblings().find('ul').slideUp('fast'); // to hide all ul expect this one
    $(this).parent('.sub-menu').children('ul').slideToggle(200);
  });



  $('.sub-menu a').click(function(open) {
    open.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```css
.example {
  height:100vh;
  background-color:lavender;
}

.sub-menu {
   overflow-anchor:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="example">Space above</div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class='sub-menu'> <a href='#' class="exposition"  data-id="divId1">1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li> When opened, i'm a description, I'm not supposed to move the page when opened or closed.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                        <li class='sub-menu'> <a href='#' class="exposition"  data-id="divId2">2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li> I'm supposed to close 1 and don't move the page up
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        
            </ul>
<div class="example">Space below</div>
```

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Revised answer**

I think this might be a simple minimum height issue for that page. By reserving the space for the hidden content, you can avoid the jump

I made a codesandbox to demonstrate the issue and the height on the list can be tweaked - remove the border when you are happy.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-currying-6vtsy?file=/index.html:467-489

Comment: Answer revised.

Comment: alright, thanks a lot, but id doesnt seem to work, Here is a gif to see what is my issue.
https://imgur.com/a/4zgrzc0

Comment: You can play around with the minimum height, i increased it to 300px to demonstrate.

Comment: yeah, but no matter the height, the problem is still there, the page is going up a bit as shown in the gif I sent...

Comment: Based on your gif, the only thing i can suggest to you is to look at your `vh` declarations, its possible the browsers are recalculating the height of the preceding div which has a `hi` on it. Instead change it to a fixed height and try again. If you intend to use `vh` my recommendation would be to review this article - https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/ - Best of luck!

Comment: here is another https://imgur.com/a/S7Avf0s if you want to see best.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you might try the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sub-menu a', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault()
     e.stopPropagation()

     $(this).parents('.sub-menu').siblings().find('ul').slideUp('fast');
     $(this).parents('.sub-menu').children('ul').slideToggle(200);
  });
```

It's good practice to bind events to the document instead of a specific element in case you might end up loading data through AJAX in the future.

**Anyhow**, I usually achieve the thing you're looking for by defining the CSS for the element, in your case .sub-menu ul, to:

```
.sub-menu ul{
   max-height:0vh; // To hide sub-menu <ul> contents
   overflow:hidden;
   transition:500ms ease; // For fancy smooth opening and closing  [1/2]
   transition:max-height 500ms ease; // Alternative, more specific [2/2]
}

.sub-menu.active ul{
   max-height:100vh;  // or any height you expect it to never exceed.
}
```

Then - with jQuery - you can do the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sub-menu a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('.sub-menu').addClass('active')
  $(this).parents('.sub-menu').siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, it doesn't work thought.
My page is still going up when I close the menus...

Comment: About the other code you sent, it seems to be working, but I get to the top imediately since its using #.

Comment: I've changed my answer (the last code bit) to incorporate a e.preventDefault() after clicking an anchor link.